# Слетает текстура, когда создаю префаб в Unity

Tags: unity3d, текстура

У меня есть родительский GameObject и вложенные в него модели. Когда я создаю префаб, у меня теряются связи с материалом у некоторых частей модели. Почему это происходит? И как этого избежать ?

Иерархия объектов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Слетает именно у гусениц :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Сами настройки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда помещаю на сцену префаб гусеницы уже без материала:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В какой конкретной ситуации проблема проявляется?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @trollingchar теряются связи, когда я создаю префаб. Допустим мне надо запомнить положение моделей в сцене. Я создаю префаб и переношу в другую сцену и уже в этом префабе нет ссылок на материал. Модель отображается как будто бы материалы не применены.

Comment: Что такое "вложенные модели"? Иерархия из объектов с MeshRenderer у каждого или у вас именно меша разбита на сабмеши? Приведите скриншоты.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker Я дописал вопрос

Comment: На всякий случай уточню, утверждая, что на гусеница "без материала", раскрыв список `Materials` в `Mesh Renderer`, там стоит `None (Material)`. Причин фиолетовой поверхности бывает несколько.